# Passing a boolean to a function instead of creating two functions

Tags: function, boolean

I have a function like the next one for instance:

```
public void setVisible(bool visible){ ... }
```

Isn't it better in such a case to create two public functions setVisible and setInvisible for readability?

Maybe internally a private function can be created to avoid duplicate code...

Comment: Readability? Not really. I had to read twice before i could see the difference between setVisible and setInvisible.

Comment: With Setters and Getters being around, would you suggest changing them aswell if they are booleans? It wouldn't really make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is a **BIG** no-no due to the following reasons :

**Readability** : There is only a very minor difference between the two keywords `setVisible()` and `setInvisible()` and its easy to mis-read while scrolling through 100s of lines of code.

**Semantics** : Having 2 distinct *setXXX()* and *setYYY()* functions implies that there exist 2 different properties. While you will know that both of the map to the same internally, this may NOT be obvious to someone new to your library/API.

**Logic** : In addition to the set functions, you would be implementing the corresponding `getVisible()` and `getInvisible()` for good measure as well. With code snippets like the following sure to cause enough confusion.

```
setVisible()  
...  
getInvisible()  

(wait, what??)

setInVisible()  
...  
getVisible()

(whats the state now??)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've known `show` and `hide` sometimes in this context, especially with windows.

I like it for emphasizing that it's not a *pure getter and setter* but some more code to actually show or hide windows. Even though this is still "just" changing the state, it might be a lot of runtime cost that a pure setter may not be expected to have.

Solely for reading or changing a flag I would not recommend it though, for reasons TheCodeArtist already pointed out.